# Need help establishing nodejs (NPM) localhost https

Tags: node.js, npm, https, aurelia

I have read over and tried a dozen different ways to get my Aurelia app (run by npm start) on Windows 10 to be served as HTTPS, but have been unable to do so.

If anyone has a clear path to do this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is your aurelia setup? Are you using the CLI and webpack for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your Best Option would be to use a 3rd Party Service like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), just download and run using the following,

```
ngrok http 80
```

This will provide you with a free https proxy from their server to you.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using BrowserSync and as sometime in 2015 it supports auto detect http vs https via the proxy config setting `{proxy: 'https://localhost:12345'}`.  So if you specify an https proxy url, browsersync should automatically fire up the proxy'd https url.  You'll have to hunt for where you're browser sync settings are located.  You can use this for the BrowserSync reference.  https://wearejh.com/https-support-added-browsersync/#how-does-it-work-

Comment: In my Aurelia setup I'm using webpack 4.0 and my browersync is under the plugins, for example.

`
...when(!isReleaseBuild, new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3000,
            proxy: 'http://localhost:60254/',  //this needs to mirror what's in the project properies > Web > Project URL (for local development only)
            startPath: 'Aurelia/IndexStandalone.aspx',
            reloadDelay: 2000
        }))
`.  What'evs!  I can't get code formatting in this comment...but you get the idea :)